# PHP / XML - Namespace not defined

Tags: php, xml, laravel

We developed a webapplication in Laravel/PHP. The application reads out customer data and puts the data into an XML. The XML is formatted according to the format of a VAT-declaration in Belgium.

When I try to open the XML in Internet Explorer, it shows a white page and I receive an error that the namespace is not defined. I do not understand this, because I believe I defined the namespace.

- Link to the full xml: [click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16CkyrXRgZX0hsMwBVXFHT1nF5kl3gtMH/view?usp=sharing)
- Preview of the XML:[pretty print xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74pvz.png)

Does anyone sees what I am doing wrong. I assume it is something stupid, but I am looking for days and I do not see what is wrong.

Thank you so much!
Kind regards,
Jer

Comment: You are defining `xmlns:ns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/VATConsignment"` and trying to use it in `ns2:VATConsignment`, they should both be `ns` or `ns2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your elements have the namespace prefix `ns2, e.g.` ns2:VATConsignment`; unfortunately this namespace prefix is never defined in your XML.

even your root element uses this undefined namespace prefix:

```
<ns2:VATConsignment xmlns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon"
                    xmlns:ns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/VATConsignment"
                    VATDeclarationsNbr="1">
```

Nonetheless it declares a namespace for itself: `xmlns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon"`

and yet another namespace with prefix that is not being used in your document: `xmlns:ns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/VATConsignment"`

Now I don't know whether all your `ns2:`elements are from the first or the latter namespace and you should check that. In any case adding the namespace prefix definition for `ns2`, or (if the elements are from the namespace defined with the `ns` prefix) changing the prefix to `ns` should fix the problem.

Here's an example of how to define the additional namespace prefix on your root element:

```
<ns2:VATConsignment xmlns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon"
                    xmlns:ns2="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon"
                    xmlns:ns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/VATConsignment"
                    VATDeclarationsNbr="1">
```

Just a side note: namespace prefixes can be freely defined in XML so using something more semantic than `ns`or `ns2` makes it a lot easier to proofread, e.g.

```
<input:VATConsignment xmlns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon"
                    xmlns:input="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon"
                    xmlns:vat="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/VATConsignment"
                    VATDeclarationsNbr="1">
```

Comment: I guess the namespace assignment of your root element might be wrong in the above example;  seems more plausible to me that the `VATConsignment` element is from the corresponding namespace `http://www.minfin.fgov.be/VATConsignment`

Comment: Hello Benjamin, you are right. That solved my problem! Thank you very much :-)

Comment: glad I could help ;-) working with XML namespaces are the most common stumbling block.
n.b. please consider voting up my answer